# Open new tab in background in Firefox with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I want to use JS to open a new tab in Firefox but in the page group. That will be Google, in the example. I want the original tab to stay focused and open Facebook. Would also work in as many other browsers as possible, ideally.

I am using this code, and it works, in a way.

The first click will open the new tab and focus on that, which is not what I need.

But, if I make the first tab, the original, go back then press it again, I get the desired behaviour. The new tab will open in the background but the original one will be the one that's focused and changes to the webpage.

```
<button type="button" onclick="open_in_bg('http://facebook.com', 'http://google.com')" >Press Me</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function open_in_bg(c_url, n_url)
    {
     window.open (n_url, "mywindow" );
     window.open (c_url+"#maintain_focus","_self");
    }
    </script>
```

My first thought is that it may be possible to replicate the result from the 2nd click for the 1st. Possible? Any viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, I do not believe this is possible. Most browsers have removed any support for controlling tabs via javascript as a security issue. This was removed to prevent pop-unders by nefarious sites.

[Here is an info about the user settings](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/force-links-to-open-in-background-firefox-chrome)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Although, I am starting to see some viable options maybe through my own research. Alerts being one method that may present a work around.